# HTML code changing but not the url (Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate the sign up process in Twitter. The url where all the process is made is https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup but at some point the HTML code changes but not the url, so Selenium keeps searching for elements in the old code and it can't find what I'm looking for in the new code.

If you want to take a look, the moment where it changes is when Twitter demands the verification code of your email.

Thanks!

Comment: use switch statements whenever you're facing html change then execute your script.